# Why does SQL Server use an Index Scan instead of a Seek + RID lookup?

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I have a table with approx. 135M rows:

```
CREATE TABLE [LargeTable]
(
    [ID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [ChildID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [ChildType] INT NOT NULL
)
```

It has a non-clustered index with no included columns:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [LargeTable_ChildID_IX]
  ON [LargeTable] 
(
    [ChildID] ASC
)
```

(It is clustered on `ID`).

I wish to join this against a temporary table which contains a few thousand rows:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    ChildID         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
    ChildType       INT
)

...add #temp data...

SELECT lt.ChildID, lt.ChildType
    FROM #temp t
    INNER  JOIN [LargeTable] lt
        ON lt.[ChildID] = t.[ChildID]
```

However the query plan includes an index scan on the large table:

[image: Index Scan]

If I change the index to include extra columns:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [LargeTable_ChildID_IX] ON [LargeTable] 
(
    [ChildID] ASC
)
INCLUDE [ChildType]
```

Then the query plan changes to something more sensible:

[image: Index Seek]

**So my question is:** Why can't SQL Server still use an index seek in the first scenario, but with a RID lookup to get from the non-clustered index to the table data? Surely that would be more efficient than an index scan on such a large table?

Comment: I have done an `UPDATE STATISTICS [LargeTable] WITH FULLSCAN`.

Comment: Always question statements that start with "Surely" or "Obviously".

Comment: You say a few thousand rows in the temp table but the query plan shows 1? Even a few thousand would be less than 0.1% which is likely under the tipping point. You could use Apply to encourage a seek and compare the results.

Comment: Absolutely, I recognise my mental model is incomplete here... just trying to get a handle on what I'm missing.

Comment: @MartinSmith - actually I ran these query plans against a completely empty temp table... with the real data, it has a few thousand rows. Apologies for the confusion. I've also renamed the table in this question, hence the slightly doctored plan images.

Comment: Do you get the plan you wanted if you change inner join to inner loop join?

Comment: Also what is the warning about in the left hand select operator?

Comment: @MartinSmith - misssing index - `ChildID INCLUDE ChildType`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query plan actually makes a lot of sense. Remember that SQL Server never reads records, it reads pages. In your table, a page contains many records, since those records are so small.

With the original index, if the second query plan would be used, after finding all the RID's in the index, and reading index pages to do so, pages in the clustered index need to be read to read the ChildType column. In a worst case scenario, that is an entire page for each record it needs to read. As there are many records per page, that might boil down to reading a large percentage of the pages in the clustered index.

SQL server guessed, based on statistics, that simply scanning the pages in the clustered index would require less page reads in total, because it then avoids reading the pages in the non-clustered index.

What matters here is the number of *rows* in the temp table compared to the number of *pages* in the large table. Assuming a random distribution of ChildID in the large table, as soon as the number of rows in the temp table approaches or supersedes the number of pages in the large table, SQL server will have to read virtually every page in the large table anyway.

Comment: OK that makes sense, when you explain like that. I guess I was hoping that since the number of rows in the temp table was so small (relative to the large table), that it would recognise that individual RID lookups would be faster.

Comment: Strangely, trying to force a seek using `WITH (FORCESEEK)` resulted in SQL Server being unable to run the query at all... I had hoped a `FORCESEEK` would also force RID lookups.

Comment: @stusmith You say the number of _rows_ in the temp table is small compared to the number of _rows_ in the large table. That doesn't matter. What matters is the number of _rows_ in the temp table compared to the number of _pages_ in the large table. Assuming a random distribution of ChildID in the large table, as soon as the number of rows in the temp table approaches or supersedes the number of pages in the large table, SQL server will have to read virtually every page in the large table anyway. I'll update my answer to include this.

Comment: The query plan shows that even for an *empty* temp table with actual rows 0 and estimated rows 1 they still get a full scan though. Does seem a poor execution plan if everything is as they describe it. For estimated one row from the temp table unless there are very many duplicates in the other table a nested loops and lookups would probably be cheaper.

Comment: @MartinSmith I agree that in that situation, this is a poor execution plan. In the other case it's not. The cost based optimizer has to make a decision, and unless instructed to do otherwise, this is the decision it makes. Merely observing a fact, and providing the reasoning behind it in my anser.

Answer (score 0):

Because the column `ChildType` isn't covered in an index, it has to go back to the clustered index (with the mentioned Row IDentifier lookup) to get the values for `ChildType`.
When you `INCLUDE` this column in the nonclustered index it will be added to the leaf-level of the index where it is available for querying.

Answer (score 0):

Colloquially is called ['the index tipping point'](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/category/the-tipping-point/). Basically, at what point does the cost based optimizer consider that is more effective to do a scan rather than seek + lookup. Usually is around 20% of the size, which in your case will base on an estimate coming from the #temp table stats. YMMV.

You already have your answer: include the required column, make the index covering.